# PHP: Can't connect to socket from php-fpm

Tags: php, sockets

I have a script, that works in background and accepts connections via unix sockets.

So, I've wrote another script, that connects to the first one.
I've checked it from the CLI and everything works just fine.
But when I'm trying to use my second script from the web (php-fpm), I'm getting exception `No such file or directory`.
This exception is thrown when `socket_connect` function is invoked.
Sounds like there is no socket file. But it does exist. And I can connect to this socket at that moment with this script but only from CLI.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code:

```
$filepath = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'checkerd.sock';

$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, null);
$result = socket_connect($socket, $filepath, 0);
if ($result === false) {
    print_r(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
}
```

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: @CodeCaster, what concrete code do you want to see?

Comment: The code you use to create the listening socket and the code you use to connect to said socket. Also, the relevant configuration settings. Perhaps the user running the client php-fpm has no permissions to connect to the listening Unix socket, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I've updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've found an answer:

`systemd` has a feature "private tmp". It mounts /tmp (and /var/tmp) as private filesystem for each process.

My socket server was run from console (on behalf of php cli). Thats why I was able to connect to it when I run my client as console script. And that's why the same script hadn't seen socket file when was run from php-fpm (another process).

The solution is to disable private tmp for php-fpm:
I've created `/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/private-tmp.conf` with the content:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=false
```

php-fpm must be restarted after this.